# PCA how to plot effect of one component

Tags: python, components, analysis, pca, principal

**EDIT AT THE BOTTOM CONTAINING SOLUTION**

I performed PCA on my dataset, resulting in the eigenvectors, eigenvalues and the mean.
I want to plot the effects of varying one principal component but I can't figure out how.
So I want to create a plot like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lQaA.png

So the formula for for this should be

> mean + Pb

with P the eigenvectors and b

> b = P.T * (x - mean)

But then I don't know what to use for x.
Another possibility according to the Active shape model paper by Cootes is that

> b = (b1 b2 .. bt).T

So a vector of weights. This makes more sense to me, this way I could have the weight of the first b set to -3 * sqrt(eigenvalue) and plot the result. But I'm having dimensionality problems this way.

My input data for the pca was [20, 160], so it returns a [160] for the mean, [160, N] with N the amount of principal components I want to retain, let's choose 5. And finally [N] eigenvalues.
So this way I can't do Pb because P is [160] which I should dotproduct with another [160]?
I'm pretty confused on how to  do this, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Ok so I figured out the problem.
When trying to plot the effect of the first principal component, I was only taking the first column of my eigenvectors, which was the mistake.

What you should do is take all of the eigenvectors P, in my case [160, 5], and create a new vector b with dimension [5]. b consists of all zeros, except on the index of the principal component you wish to change, where you put e.g. -2 * sqrt(eigenvalue_i), to plot the effect of varying principal component i, 2 standard deviations to the left.
So this result in

> x = mu + P * b

with mu = mean, P complete set of eigenvectors, and b a vector containing the weights of the variation.